# I cannot rename table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, languages

I'm writing a document in Spanish (with babel), but the name of `\tableofcontents` is still "Contents". I've tried with `\renewcommand{\contentsname}`, `\addto\captionsspanish` and a lot of different combinations but it doesn't work.

I don't know what is happening, because the name of the bibliography is in Spanish, so babel is working properly there.

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,aps,prd,preprintnumbers,nofootinbibn,onecolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}  
\usepackage{bm}       
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*\Dif[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
\hyphenation{ALPGEN}
\hyphenation{EVTGEN}
\hyphenation{PYTHIA}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{0cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.6cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0cm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{a4paper, total={160mm,247mm}, left=25mm, top=25mm, }
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{\huge{Título}\\[0.4cm]}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\begin{center}
\today\\
\vspace{1cm}

\hspace{1em}{\bf Autor:}\\
\vspace{0.1cm}
\hspace{1em}NAME $^\ddagger$\\
\vspace{0.8cm}
{\it Universidad}\vspace{2em}
\end{center}
\hline\vspace{1em}
{\bf Abstract:} \vspace{-0.5em}
\singlespacing
\small{...}\vspace{2em}\hline \vspace{1em}
\scriptsize{$^\ddagger$  E-mail: \texttt{...}
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\maketitle

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\spacing{2}
\begin{quotation}
\tableofcontents
\end{quotation}

\section{Introducción}
\setcounter{page}{1} 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1}
...

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't work, no variation of \renewcommand{\contentsname} seems to change the name in my document.

Comment: Alright, I've a look. Please wrap that long lines with `\usepackage{...}` at the beginning, that's awful.... You're loading some packages, `epsfig` is outdated and why manipulating layout parameters whereas you use `geometry` already?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here ... How do I wrap lines?

Comment: Using the newline 'enter' key on your keyboard?

Comment: Probably some of the commands aren't needed, but the sample for the document was given to me with all of them. They've worked properly other times so I think the problem with `\tableofcontents` is not there...

Comment: note size change commands like `\small` and `huge` do not take an argument so `\small ...` not `\small{...}` commands  `\bf` and `\it` are deprecated and don't load `epsfig` unless you need to emulate a document using a package from 1990.

Comment: Your document's preamble loads quite a few packages that are either deprecated (e.g., `subfigure`), fully or nearly duplicative (e.g., `epsfig`, given that you also load `graphicx`), almost surely unneeded (`shapepar` -- really?!), or get loaded more than once (e.g., `amsmath`). The preamble also contains statements that are subsequently overridden by later statements. E.g., why modify `\hoffset` and `\voffset` by hand if you then go on to load the `geometry` package and issue a `\geometry` statement? Do yourself a big favor and simplify and shorten the document's preamble.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the `ToC` is stored in `\tocname`.

Use

```
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tocname}{Índice}}
```

instead of `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}}`

```
\documentclass[11pt,aps,prd,preprintnumbers,nofootinbibn,onecolumn]{revtex4}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tocname}{Índice}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introducción}

\end{document}
```

I kicked all unnecessary (and wrong content) out of the preamble

[image]

Comment: Ok, it is working now! The name apperas properly adding that command line. Thank you very much! @Christian Hupfer

Do I need to erase all the other packages? Some of them are needed for math equations...

Comment: @TsuKi: Just for shortness. Your document was not compilable at all.

Comment: @TsuKi but only put back the packages that you actually use. It makes no sense at all to have lipsum, blindtext, epsfig in a current math paper and probably not shapepar, stackengine, better to use `utf8` than `utf8x` and only load chemmacros if you are using that chemistry package, etc.

Comment: Belated congratulations on passing the 100k rep mark!!

Comment: Please consider to accept this answer since it was the solution